# Vue 3 and Vuetify 3 access SCSS/SASS Varriables in Components

Tags: vue.js, sass, vuetify.js

I would like to use predefined variables in my Vue 3 components.

```
<template>
  <div class="rounded img-container">
    <span v-if="!props.ready">Du musst noch ein Bild aufnehmen!</span>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { defineProps } from "vue";

const props = defineProps({
  ready: { type: Boolean, required: true }
})
</script>
<style lang="scss" scoped>

.img-container {
  aspect-ratio: 3 / 2;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background: $red; <- Error
}

.text-small {
  font-size: 2em;
}
</style>
```

Unfortunately, I get an error "SassError: Undefined variable.".
What do I have to import to use the global variables of Vuetify?

Comment: Did you install `npm install sass`?

Comment: Yes. The project is running cleanly. The only thing I can't manage is the use of global SCSS/SASS variables from vuetify that are defined here. https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/vuetify/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the use of those colors is not **that** straight forward.

It is documented here  https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/sass-variables/#webpack-install
note `Requires sass-loader@^7.0.0` and changes to webpack config

You can also skip that, if in your component file you import the color variables (your amount of `../` may vary)

```
@import '../../node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/settings/_colors.scss';
```

next thing to keep in mind is the structure of the object

here is an excerpt

```css
$red: () !default;
$red: map-deep-merge(
  (
    'base': #F44336,
    'lighten-5': #FFEBEE,
    'lighten-4': #FFCDD2,
    'lighten-3': #EF9A9A,
    'lighten-2': #E57373,
    'lighten-1': #EF5350,
    'darken-1': #E53935,
    'darken-2': #D32F2F,
    'darken-3': #C62828,
    'darken-4': #B71C1C,
    'accent-1': #FF8A80,
    'accent-2': #FF5252,
    'accent-3': #FF1744,
    'accent-4': #D50000
  ),
  $red
);

/* other colors... */

$colors: () !default;
$colors: map-deep-merge(
  (
    'red': $red,
    'pink': $pink,
    'purple': $purple,
    'deep-purple': $deep-purple,
    'indigo': $indigo,
    'blue': $blue,
    'light-blue': $light-blue,
    'cyan': $cyan,
    'teal': $teal,
    'green': $green,
    'light-green': $light-green,
    'lime': $lime,
    'yellow': $yellow,
    'amber': $amber,
    'orange': $orange,
    'deep-orange': $deep-orange,
    'brown': $brown,
    'blue-grey': $blue-grey,
    'grey': $grey,
    'shades': $shades
  ),
  $colors
);
```

so the colors are not mapped to a string, but to an object (see `map-deep-merge`) so you cannot use `$red` to give you the color value.

Instead, you would use `map-deep-get` function to get the base red

```css
.class{
  background: map-deep-get($colors, "red", "base");
  /* OR */
  background:  map-get($red, "base");
}
```

so it would look like this

```html
<style lang="scss" scoped>

@import '../../node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/settings/_colors.scss';
.img-container {
  aspect-ratio: 3 / 2;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background:  map-deep-get($colors, "red", "base");
  /* OR */
  background:  map-get($red, "base");
}

.text-small {
  font-size: 2em;
}
</style>
```

Comment: If needed, it is possible to config `vue.config.js` or `vite.config.js` with something like  `scss: { additionalData: @import "~@/scss/_variables.scss"; }` to enable access of variables to every file

Comment: @lestra Thank you both very much. You have steered me in the right direction. I have now entered the following in vue.config.js: 
`
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      scss: {
        additionalData: `@import "./node_modules/vuetify/lib/styles/settings/_colors.scss";`,
      },
    },
  }
`
After that I can now access the colours in the component. 
I have one last question, how can I access the primary and secondary colours?

Comment: Okay, get it. You can access the colours via JS.  var vueColor = ref(theme.current.value.colors.primary); And then you could use it in the css  background: v-bind(vueColor);