# How to Use Vuetify 3 SCSS Variables in Nuxt 3 Component

Tags: sass, vuejs3, vuetify.js, nuxtjs3, vuetifyjs3

I need something like this

```css
  .title {
    color: $primary;
  }
```

`$primary` is inheritance from vuetify css styles.

I tried the answer here [Vue 3 and Vuetify 3 access SCSS/SASS Varriables in Components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73340896/vue-3-and-vuetify-3-access-scss-sass-varriables-in-components).

The problem is vuetify folder structure and naming is changing to

```
--vuetify
-----settings.scss
-----styles.scss
```